# TypeError: data type not understood

Tags: python3, tensorflow, numpy, 深層学習

以下のサンプルスクリプトを実行しようとしていますが、
https://github.com/carpedm20/DCGAN-tensorflow
以下コード部分でErrorが発生し実行できません。

```py
(utils.py)
  im = Image.fromarray(x[j:j+crop_h, i:i+crop_w])
  return np.array(im.resize([resize_h, resize_w]), PIL.Image.BILINEAR)
```

最初は**[TypeError: Cannot handle this data type]**が出力されたので、
以下のように修正しました。

```py
(utils.py)
  im = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(np.asarray(x[j:j+crop_h, i:i+crop_w])))
  return np.array(im.resize([resize_h, resize_w]), PIL.Image.BILINEAR)
```

しかし、今度は以下のようなErrorが発生しました。

```
W1110 08:35:35.579368 10508 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From C:\Users\READY\AnacondaProjects\DCGAN2\DCGAN-tensorflow-master\model.py:164: The name tf.train.AdamOptimizer is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer instead.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 147, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "C:\Users\READY\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\TensorFlow20gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "C:\Users\READY\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\TensorFlow20gpu\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 300, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "C:\Users\READY\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\TensorFlow20gpu\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "main.py", line 120, in main
    dcgan.train(FLAGS)
  File "C:\Users\READY\AnacondaProjects\DCGAN2\DCGAN-tensorflow-master\model.py", line 195, in train
    grayscale=self.grayscale) for sample_file in sample_files]
  File "C:\Users\READY\AnacondaProjects\DCGAN2\DCGAN-tensorflow-master\model.py", line 195, in <listcomp>
    grayscale=self.grayscale) for sample_file in sample_files]
  File "C:\Users\READY\AnacondaProjects\DCGAN2\DCGAN-tensorflow-master\utils.py", line 46, in get_image
    resize_height, resize_width, crop)
  File "C:\Users\READY\AnacondaProjects\DCGAN2\DCGAN-tensorflow-master\utils.py", line 104, in transform
    resize_height, resize_width)
  File "C:\Users\READY\AnacondaProjects\DCGAN2\DCGAN-tensorflow-master\utils.py", line 97, in center_crop
    return np.array(im.resize([resize_h, resize_w]), PIL.Image.BILINEAR)
TypeError: data type not understood
```

どう修正すれば解決するのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
return np.array(im.resize([resize_h, resize_w]), PIL.Image.BILINEAR)
```

だと，`PIL.Image.BILINEAR`を`np.array`に渡してしまっているので，

```py
return np.array(im.resize([resize_h, resize_w], PIL.Image.BILINEAR))
```

と，`im.resize`に渡してあげる必要があると思います．

Comment: ありがとうございます。解決しました。

Comment: 解決したなら何よりですが，であれば承認していただけると．